# Do you say shehechiyanu on a new flavor of tea?

Tags: halacha, blessing, shehecheyanu

There are a ton of different flavors of teas out there.
Usually these teas are made from leaves - and they actually contain the leaves.

Does one say shehechiyanu on a new type of tea if he hasn't tasted it in the past 6 months?

Some chamomile tea you can toss into a cup of hot water:

[image: chamomile]

And some loose leaf green tea:

[image: black tea leaves]

Comment: "past 6 months"? Why would that matter?

Comment: @DoubleAA, I think it's a tosfos some place (brachot 6th perek)...

Answer (score 3):

The following extracts from [Halachically Speaking](http://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/halacha/Tu_Beshevat__10.pdf) seem to be relevant.
Each of the sections that I put in bold seem to indicate that no  shehechiyanu is needed.

> The Beracha on Fruits and those who are lenient
>
> When a fruit is only available once a year a shehechiyanu is recited
>   because the new fruits bring joy to a person. Based on this some
>   people have the custom not to recite a beracha on new fruits because
>   there is no real joy with the new fruit.
>
> The beracha of shehechiyanu is recited on new fruits which were not
>   available all year (below we will discuss the fact that many fruits
>   are available all year). **One does not recite a shehechiyanu on a
>   fruit which is not seasonal.**
>
> Dried Fruits 
>   **A fruit which was not available all year round but is being sold as dried fruit would not require a shehechiyanu before eating it.**
>
> Smashed Fruit - Jam 
>   **New fruits which are smashed to the point where it is not recognizable that they are fruits do not require a shehechiyanu. 
>   However, if there are pieces of the fruit which are discernible then a
>   beracha can be recited. The same applies to a drink made from a new
>   fruit.**

So the three reasons not to make a  shehechiyanu are:

The teas are not seasonal.

Even if they were seasonal, they are being used in a dried form.

The pieces of the “fruit” are not discernible in the tea.